# MySQL Query is Extremely Slow

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization

Hello I am looking for ways to optimize the mysql query, basically I am fetching the articles for the user which belong to category_id = 25 and source_id not in a table where I store source id's from which user has unsubscribed.

```
select
  a.article_id,
  a.article_title,
  a.source_id,
  a.article_publish_date,
  a.article_details,
  n.source_name
from sources n
  INNER JOIN articles a
    ON (a.source_id = n.source_id)
WHERE n.category_id = 25
    AND n.source_id NOT IN(select
                 source_id
               from news_sources_deselected
               WHERE user_id = 5)
ORDER BY a.article_publish_date DESC
```

**Schema for Articles Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (<br>
  `article_id` int(255) NOT NULL auto_increment,<br>
  `article_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,<br>
  `source_id` int(255) NOT NULL,<br>
  `article_publish_date` bigint(255) NOT NULL,<br>
  `article_details` text NOT NULL,<br>
  PRIMARY KEY  (`article_id`),<br>
  KEY `source_id` (`source_id`),<br>
  KEY `article_publish_date` (`article_publish_date`)<br>
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Contains articles.';
```

**Structure for Sources table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sources` (<br>
  `source_id` int(255) NOT NULL auto_increment,<br>
  `category_id` int(255) NOT NULL,<br>
  `source_name` varchar(255) character set latin1 NOT NULL,<br>
  `user_id` int(255) NOT NULL,<br>
  PRIMARY KEY  (`source_id`),<br>
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),<br>
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='News Sources.'
```

The articles table has around 0.3 Million records and sources table contains around 1000 records, the query takes around 180 seconds to execute.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Migrated as requested.

Comment: what version of mysql are you using? there are some query planner improvements for subqueries in 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by partitioning the table, but I am still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a derieved query with IS NULL condition. You explain says there is a dependent subquery. Ignore using it and use derieved query for your problem. This will increase the performance

```
select
  a.article_id,
  a.article_title,
  a.source_id,
  a.article_publish_date,
  a.article_details,
  n.source_name
from sources n
  INNER JOIN articles a
    ON (a.source_id = n.source_id)
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
         FROM news_sources_deselected
         WHERE user_id = 5) AS nsd
    ON nsd.source_id = n.source_id
WHERE n.category_id = 25
    AND nsd.source_id IS NULL
ORDER BY a.article_publish_date DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, no improvement with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPLAIN in front of your query and analyze results.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) you can find how to start your optimization work.

Answer (score 0):

I see few issues you could check.

- You're not using relations despite using InnoDB engine.
- You're selecting fields without index.
- You're selecting all rows at once.

Do you need all those rows at once? Maybe consider splitting this query to multiple shards (paging)?

Comment: what does selecting fields without index means?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select
 a.article_id,
 a.article_title,
 a.source_id,
 a.article_publish_date,
 a.article_details,
 n.source_name
from 
 sources n
INNER JOIN 
 articles a
ON 
 n.category_id = 25 AND 
 a.source_id = n.source_id     
INNER JOIN 
 news_sources_deselected nsd
ON
 nsd.user_id <> 5 AND n.source_id = nsd.source_id
ORDER BY 
 a.article_publish_date DESC
```

I have removed the extra query and added `news_sources_deselected` in join by accepting all `source_id` for `user_id` other than with id `5`.

Or we can go for using only needed records for join as user raheelshan has mentioned

```
select
 a.article_id,
 a.article_title,
 a.source_id,
 a.article_publish_date,
 a.article_details,
 n.source_name
from 
 (select 
   * 
 from 
   sources 
 where 
   category_id = 25) n 
INNER JOIN 
 articles a
ON 
 a.source_id = n.source_id     
INNER JOIN 
 (select 
   * 
 from 
   news_sources_deselected 
 where 
   user_id <> 5) nsd
ON
 n.source_id = nsd.source_id
ORDER BY 
 a.article_publish_date DESC
```

Hope this helps..